# Avoiding relative Paths for Angular projects in the workspace

Tags: angular

First of all, I should say that I have created my Angular workspace with the following command:

```
ng new angular-apps --create-application=false
```

tsconfig.json in the root of the workspace :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

then created one project in this workspace with the following command :

```
ng generate application cac-web
```

This is the tsconfig.app.json that is in the root of cac-web app:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "moduleResolution":"classic",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "app/*"
      ],
      "@app/core/*": [
        "app/core/*"
      ],
      "@app/shared/*": [
        "app/shared/*"
      ],
      "@env/*": [
        "environments/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

In the cac-web app, I have created the shared module and then (models folder/student.model.ts)
when I want to use this model in another module, I get the following error?

[image]

Cannot find module '@app/shared/models/student.model'

**EDIT :**

here is the structure of my project :

```
|node_modules
|projects--------------cac-web|e2e-----------------|src
|                             |                    |protractor.conf.js
|                             |                    |tsconfig.json
|                             |src-----------------|app-----------------|client(Module)-----------------|client-list(component)
|                             |                    |                    |shared(Module)-----------------|models(student.model.ts)
|                             |                    |                    |                               |shared.module.ts
|                             |                    |                    |app-routing.module.ts
|                             |                    |                    |app.component.html
|                             |                    |                    |app.component.ts
|                             |                    |                    |app.module.ts
|                             |                    |assets
|                             |                    |environments
|                             |                    |index.html
|                             |                    |main.ts
|                             |                    |polyfills.ts
|                             |                    |styles.css
|                             |                    |test.ts
|                             |browserslist
|                             |karma.conf.js
|                             |tsconfig.app.json
|                             |tsconfig.spec.json
|                             |tslint.json
|.editorconfig
|.gitignore
|angular.json
|package-lock.json
|package.json
|README.md
|tsconfig.json
|tslint.json
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but I don't think the glob in your tsconfig.app.json corresponding to the `shared` folder includes subdirectories. Could you try `@app/shared/**/*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't change the `tsconfig.app.json` file.

Modify your main `tsconfig.json` this way per each new project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "projects/cac-web/src/app/*"
      ],
      "@app/core/*": [
        "projects/cac-web/src/app/core/*"
      ],
      "@app/shared/*": [
        "projects/cac-web/src/app/shared/*"
      ],
      "@env/*": [
        "projects/cac-web/src/environments/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Really I was stuck thank you very much @VahidN

Comment: So how do I configure the similar paths for a second project, `abc-web`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change your tsconfig.json like this

Note: tsconfig.json have to be same level as src folder

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "src/app/*"
      ],
      "@app/core/*": [
        "src/app/core/*"
      ],
      "@app/shared/*": [
        "src/app/shared/*"
      ],
      "@env/*": [
        "src/environments/*"
      ]
    }
```

Also restart your angular cli server after you change tsconfig.json

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How about tsconfig.app.json, and How it should be?

Comment: unfortunately, It does not work. I updated my question by adding the structure of the project because I guess you are thinking that there is a folder named src in the root of workspace but not. thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently working on one of the apps I have running in production.

Here is what my `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@guards/*": ["app/guards/*"],
      "@interceptors/*": ["app/interceptors/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["app/modules/*"],
      "@utilities/*": ["app/utilities/*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2016",
      "es2017.object"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  }
}
```

Here is what my `tsconfig.app.json` looks like:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@guards/*": ["app/guards/*"],
      "@interceptors/*": ["app/interceptors/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["app/modules/*"],
      "@utilities/*": ["app/utilities/*"]
    },
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [],
    "target": "es5",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2016",
      "es2017.object"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How about tsconfig.app.json, and How it should be?

Comment: @AbolfazlR - Updated with tsconfig.app.json

Comment: @ Andrew Hill - if you look at the structure of the project in my question carefully, there is no folder named src in the root of the workspace . In the tsconfig.json above, the value of baseUrl property is "./src" (this folder dose not exit in the root of workspace)