# Angular workspace - paths configuration for multiple projects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two projects - `app-x` and `app-z` in an Angular workspace, and I am trying to shorten my import paths. I have come across several related posts here on SO, but couldn't find the solution I'm looking for my scenario.

I have a `_core` folder in both projects and I have imports like below -

```js
import { ISomething } from 'projects/app-x/src/app/_core/infrastructure/interfaces';
// or relative equivqlent -
// import { ISomething } from '../../../_core/infrastructure/Interfaces';

import { ISomethingElse } from 'projects/app-z/src/app/_core/infrastructure/interfaces';
// or relative equivqlent -
// import { ISomethingElse } from '../../../_core/infrastructure/Interfaces';
```

I want to be able to write them as -

```js
import { ISomething } from '@core/infrastructure/interfaces';

// and -
import { ISomethingElse } from '@core/infrastructure/interfaces';
```

in their respective project.

Following is how I have tried to configure the path for project `app-x` in the `tsconfig.app.json` file generated for this project -

```json
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
        "types": [],
        "paths": {
            "@core/*": [
                "projects/app-x/src/app/_core/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

But it doesn't work, VS Code shows red squiggles with -

> Cannot find module '@core/infrastructure/Interfaces' or its
> corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57571796/446519) suggests to add the path configuration to the `tsconfig.json` file at the workspace root, and not to the `tsconfig.app.json` file. I know that works, but then I cannot use `@core` in `app-z` project since it is pointing to the `_core` folder of `app-x` project.

That is why I'm trying to put the configuration to the respective `tsconfig.app.json` files. I tweaked the `paths` option with several values, and also added a `baseUrl` option (even though one is present in the root `tsconfig.json`) and tried several values in combination of different `paths` values. But failed.

Any help, tip/suggestion, would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did you find as solution for this issue? we have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

- rename `tsconfig.app.json` to `tsconfig.json`.
- config `tsConfig` that under app-x in `anuglar.json` to this `projects/app-x/tsconfig.json`

It works for me.